# How to add placemarks to track in Google Earth?

Tags: python, google-maps, navigation, kml, google-earth

I'm trying to add placemarks on a track in Google Earth.

Imagine that I'm riding my bike through a neighborhood and take note of the open houses that I see.

I've gotten the track where it shows my path through the neighborhood. Now I would like the open houses to pop on the map as placemarks as my icon drives past the path.

What's the best way to do that?

I've recorded the data to a CSV file and trying to write the conversion in Python.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [static maps api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/), which you can do something like

```
head="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap"
marker1="&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794"
marker2="&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318"
marker3="&markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284"
print head + marker1 + marker2
```

or.. you can translate your css into json and make the javascript api to display your result.

Answer (score 0):

Actually - it turns out that if you put the path in one folder and put the Placemarks in another - it works out.